# SQL - for each (if... then... else...)

Tags: sql, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to test a sql database that I created. To do so, I've got 2 tables: items and brands. Items store different fields including the name of a brand, and brands store other fields including a name. I would like to check that for each brand in items, there is a corresponding name in brands table. How would I do that ? I thought of something along the lines of:

```
"for each row in items"
if (count(select * from items join brands on items.brand = brands.name) == 0, select items.name, '');
```

But then I don't know how to include the for statement in it... Any ideas?

Comment: Once you're done filling your brands table, you might establish a relationship between items and brands so you don't have to worry about this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT items.name 
FROM items LEFT JOIN brands
    ON items.brand = brands.name
WHERE brands.name IS NULL
ORDER BY items.name
```

With this query you get all records from items table, join them with corresponing brands records (if they exists) and finally take the ones not having brands corresponding record.

Comment: Make that items.brand = brands.name.  And it will be faster if you store the brandID rather than the brand name in the Items table: sql is better at looking for numbers than strings: items.brandID = brands.ID.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for :) Unfortunately, I sometimes change the brand IDs for some reason, therefore I can't quite store them into items, otherwise I'd have to change them all the time.

Comment: @user1329780: remember you should [accept an asnwer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @Number int;
 SET @Number = 50;
 IF @Number > 100
  PRINT 'The number is large.';
```

ELSE 
    BEGIN
       IF @Number < 10
       PRINT 'The number is small.';
       ELSE
      PRINT 'The number is medium.';
     END ;
     GO

Answer (score 0):

So what you really want to know about is all of the items that have a brand that doesn't exist in the brands table.

They are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand
FROM items i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM brands b
  WHERE i.brand = b.brand
)
```

I suggest that you:

```
ALTER TABLE item WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT item_FK_brand FOREIGN KEY (brand) REFERENCES brand (brand)
```